# Compute surface area about the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, surfaces

> Compute the surface area swept out if the graph $y = e^{-x}$, for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, is revolved about the $x$-axis.

The formula for the surface area is

> $$S = 2\pi\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \sqrt{1 + f'(x)^{2}}\, dx.$$

So, 
$$
S = 2\pi \int_{0}^{1} e^{-x} \sqrt{1 + e^{-2x}}\, dx.
$$

My professor recommended that I use trig substitution from this point. I tried letting $e^{-x} = \tan\theta$, but I think my limits of integration would be undefined [$-\ln(\tan 0)$].  Just this starting point would be helpful.

I also tried letting $u = -e^{-x}$, but it didn't really help.

Comment: The trig sub is fine. But if $x=0$ then the angle is pi/4 and if $x=1$ then the angle cannot be determined. So it is better to do the trig sub, calculate the anti derivative and back sub in terms of $x$. Don't forget to relate the e-power and the tangent in a right triangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $u=e^{-x}$, we have 
$$\int_0^1 e^{-x} \sqrt{1+e^{-2x}} dx=-\int_1^{1/e}\sqrt{1+u^2} du=\int_{1/e}^1\sqrt{1+u^2} du$$

This last integral can be done with a trig substitution, or can be looked in a table of standard integrals. The limits of integration shouldn't cause any problems.